# 'int' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python

Some advice was given here

[Python Sockets use function instead of global socket call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569044/python-sockets-use-function-instead-of-global-socket-call)

and I thought it was working but now seems to not be any ideas on how to make the following code work?

```
def testMethod():
    socks = {}
    socks['i'] = createConnection(host, port)
    socks['i'].send("Hello  world")
    print "Sent Hello World"
```

This is the error message I get

```
'int' object has no attribute 'send'
```

*cheers

and ty for any advice

Comment: It appears your version of `createConnection()` returns an `int` instead, what does your version look like?

Comment: thank you that helped solve my issue and on to the next one :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your createConnection function.  It is returning an int rather than a socket.  Can you share your implementation of createConnection?

To make this more answer like:

In your case, createConnection is returning an integer, a socket handle perhaps, but I'm guessing because the implementation isn't available.

the method should look something like

```
import socket
def createConnetion(host, port):
  sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  sock.connect((host, port))
  return sock
```

Comment: This is not really an answer, but a comment, isn't it.

Comment: It is, but I didn't have the reputation to comment.